# Setting the cursor to the open hand in Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps

I'm developing with Bing Maps AJAX V7 map API and I'm trying to set the cursor to different things while hovering over different map elements. For example this is what I'm doing when the mouse rolls over a pushpin:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(g_map, "mousemove", function (event) {
    if (event.targetType === "pushpin") {
        g_map.getRootElement().style.cursor = "pointer";
    }
});
```

What I can't figure out is how to revert back to normal functionality after the user mouses out of the pushpin. I was thinking maybe set the cursor to pointer on mouseenter and back to non-pointer on mouseleave or something but I'm not sure if that's the best way.

Comment: Since you are handling the event on the base map, you can just have an else case and revert the cursor to default.

Answer (score 6):

You're using the event on the base map so I would recommend to bind the event on the pushpin itself to avoid unnecessary call of this specific event.

But if you want to update your code, here is a complete example that truly works since the 'hand' is the default element in Bing Maps while the mouse is over the base map, see the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Bing Maps Cursor</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;

        function getMap() {

            // Initialize the map
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                credentials: "YOURKEY",
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.5, 2.75),
                zoom: 4,
                mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road
            });

            var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.5, 2.75));
            map.entities.push(pin);    

            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'mousemove', function(event) {
                if(event.targetType === 'pushpin') {
                    map.getRootElement().style.cursor = 'pointer';
                } else {
                    map.getRootElement().style.cursor = 'url("' + Microsoft.Maps.Globals.cursorPath + 'grab.cur"), move';
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getMap();">
    <div id="map" style="position: relative; width: 800px; height: 600px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you want the recommend approach based on the pushpin event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Bing Maps Cursor</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;
        var cursorStyle = null;

        function getMap() {

            // Initialize the map
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                credentials: "YOURKEY",
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.5, 2.75),
                zoom: 4,
                mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road
            });

            var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.5, 2.75));
            map.entities.push(pin);    

            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mouseover', changeCursor);
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mouseout', revertCursor);    
        }

        function changeCursor(e) { 
            map.getRootElement().style.cursor = 'pointer';
        }
        function revertCursor(e) { 
            map.getRootElement().style.cursor = 'url("' + Microsoft.Maps.Globals.cursorPath + 'grab.cur"), move';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getMap();">
    <div id="map" style="position: relative; width: 800px; height: 600px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perfect answer Thank you

Comment: https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/v7.0/cursors/grab.cur no longer exists

Comment: Fixed with the dynamic url: Microsoft.Maps.Globals.cursorPath + 'grab.cur'

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to accomplish a similar task - change cursor to a pointer when hovering over a pushpin. I've tried several solutions with event handlers - different combinations of 'mouseout', 'mouseover' events for the map and each pin. I had a couple of problems with those approaches: sometimes event handlers weren't called as expected and my cursor was sticking to a pointer after hovering over a pushpin, reverting cusrsor back to a drag-and-drop required me to reference bing's custom cursor (https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/v7.0/7.0.20140318165546.99/cursors/grab.cur), which is unreliable because this link can change at any time.

So, a better, in my opinion, solution to change pushpin cursor is this:

```
<style>
    .MapPushpinBase { cursor: pointer !important; }
</style>
```

In my case it reverts back to an appropriate cursor when needed and doesn't require me to reference bing's resources.

I'm not sure, however, if that can be applied to other entity types, like polylines. Also, this solution will apply cursor styling for each pushpin on the page, so you might want to tinker with pushpin styles a little.

UPD:

If you don't want to mess with bing's base styles you can apply custom CSS class to pushpins, which you'd like to have pointer cursor, like this:

```
.my-pin {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

And in Javascript:

```
new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, {typeName: 'my-pin'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've need to do something similar(change mouse cursor depending on what the mouse is currently hovering over), and I've used the `mouseout` event to set the cursor back to `default`:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(g_map, "mouseout", function (event) {
    if (event.targetType === "pushpin") {
        g_map.getRootElement().style.cursor = "default";
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that the Bing maps ajax control changes the mouse cursor by itself all the time when you are interacting with the map via the mouse, so sometimes you will get into odd visual states with the mouse pointer if you also change it yourself.  Not a big deal, you just need to be aware of it.

Comment: The default cursor is not the one used on the map control (it's an hand by default). 
Adding to this, you do not have to use mouseout on global elements but rather use the mousemove on the other element type or use mouseout on the specific pushpin element.